# Regex to find by ignoring certain words

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am very new with regex. I want to search for multiple words in a string by ignoring common words like "in", "of", "the" and special characters like comma, backslash etc.

My Code

```
  Dim StringToSearchFrom As String = "Thus, one shifts one's focus in a variety of directions all at the same time"
  Dim PhraseToSearch As String = "focus variety directions"
  Dim found1 As Match = Regex.Match(StringToSearchFrom, Regex needed)
        If found1.Success Then
            MsgBox(found1.Index)
        Else
```

First regex should ignore the complete words "in", "a" and "of" while trying to find and then return the index of the first word (focus ) of `PhraseToSearch`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression, that you will have to build dynamically. Here is a proof-of-concept example that will capture "focus variety" in your string ignoring "a" and "in":

```
Public Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex( _
      "focus(?:(?:\b(?:in|of|a|the)\b\s*|[\p{P}\p{S}\p{Z}]*)*)variety", _
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase _
    Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant _
    Or RegexOptions.Compiled _
    )
```

**Explanation**:

To make a part of string optional, we should still be able to capture it in the pattern. If you replace all optional substrings in your query string with `(?:(?:\b(?:in|of|a|the)\b\s*|[\p{P}\p{S}\p{Z}]*)*)`, you will be able to match any words in the word list `(?:in|of|a|the)` (update with your word list), punctuation `\p{P}`, symbols `\p{S}`, whitespace `\p{Z}`.

```
  Dim StringToSearchFrom As String = "Thus, one shifts one's focus in a variety of directions all at the same time"
  Dim PhraseToSearch As String = "focus variety directions"
  Dim optional_pattern As String = "(?:(?:\b(?:in|of|a|the)\b\s*|[\p{P}\p{S}\p{Z}]*)*)" 
  Dim rgx_Optional As New Regex(optional_pattern)
  PhraseToSearch = rgx_Optional.Replace(PhraseToSearch, optional_pattern)
  Dim rgx_Search As New Regex(PhraseToSearch)
  ' And then apply our regex
  Dim found1 As Match = rgx_Search.Match(StringToSearchFrom)
    If found1.Success Then
        MsgBox(found1.Index)
    Else
```

Comment: Thanks you very much but I am getting an error "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Match' can be called with these arguments:'Public Function Match ..." at Regex.Match(StringToSearchFrom, rgx_Search)

Comment: Yeah, I just copied your code without checking. I replaced it to `Dim found1 As Match = rgx_Search.Match(StringToSearchFrom)`